# Exclude inner tag html using XPATH

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have a HTML

```
......<div class="p_value">Resale
    <a href="https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyservices/legal-services?inc=pdp_verify_buy_web" target="_blank" style="color: #d8232a; display: block;">Get Documents Verified</a>
</div>....
```

The expected output: `Resale`

My incorrect output: `Resale    Get Documents Verified`

My formula: `=IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'Transaction type']/following-sibling::div")`

How do I exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
//div/text()
```

or

```
//div[@class="p_value"]/text()
```